# how to draw on surface created from TextureRegistry.SurfaceTextureEntry

Tags: android, flutter, textures, surface

I want to user Texture in flutter, and then use java to paint the surface created by TextureRegistry.SurfaceTextureEntry; but I can't draw rect using the canvas get from the surface;

```
    TextureRegistry.SurfaceTextureEntry entry = textures.createSurfaceTexture();
    SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = entry.surfaceTexture();
    Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
    Canvas canvas = surface.lockCanvas(null);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.RED); 
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0,100 , 100, paint); 
    surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    result.success(entry.id());
```

I get solid blue page with no rect, and if I draw

```
canvas.drawRect(1, 1,100 , 100, paint);
```

I got completely red ;

I just want to how to paint the surface created from TextureRegistry.SurfaceTextureEntry of flutter. any such example are also ok, but i can't find it;

Comment: when I get the size of the canva, I got only 1. what is the reason